# All but one ticklabel are showing up in polar plot

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I have a problem using custom xticklabels in my polar plot. I need the exact xtick sequence specified by xticklabels but no matter what I do, the first label for 120° is not displayed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[
            xmin=0,xmax=360,
            xticklabels={120$^\circ$,90$^\circ$,60$^\circ$,30$^\circ$,0$^\circ$,330$^\circ$,300$^\circ$,270$^\circ$,240$^\circ$,210$^\circ$,180$^\circ$,150$^\circ$},
            width = 0.5\textwidth,
            no markers,
            xticklabel style={font=\large}]
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Right now, compilation fails with errors.

Comment: Why do you want to put the wrong labels on? Why do you want to put e.g. 90 for 0 or whatever rather than 0 for 0 and 90 for 90? If you remove the `xticklabels` line and fix the problems with the preamble, you get a full set of labels at the appropriate places.

Comment: I'm sorry about the code; now it should work. The problem is that the data I want to plot refers to the "wrong" labels. For me it is much easier to just modify the labels than changing the data set.

Comment: @cfr They're not wrong if you want to plot the degrees of a compass, where north is 0, east is 90, etc. For example if you're plotting vectors of wind speed or ocean current.

Comment: @cfr (Too early in the morning, didn't think.) You're right of course, they will be wrong compared to the data, so one has to transform the data as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's what I was trying to say, but you've put the point much more clearly than I managed to last night.

Comment: I added a new part to my answer (see bottom). Is any of it useful?

Answer (score 4):

## `y dir=reverse`

In the question [Rotating polar pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308670/rotating-polar-pgfplot) MajorC shows a *much* simpler way of achieving this, so my old answer (see below) is left only as a curiosity. All that's needed are the `axis` options

```
 y dir=reverse,rotate=90,
 xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    y dir=reverse,rotate=90,
    xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90}, 
    y tick label style={left},
]

\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(45,0.25)};
\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(135,0.5)};
\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(225,0.75)};
\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(315,1)};

\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Old answer: horrible workaround

---

For a more direct solution to your question, see the bottom of the answer.

---

Here is a different approach, where the axis is rotated and flipped so that the angles are as desired. This is done with the `axis` options `x post scale=-1,rotate=-90`. The rotation puts zero at the top, the scaling flips it around the north-south axis.

The other new options for the axis are

- `xtick=\ticklist`: Because the list of ticks are used twice, it's saved to a macro with `\newcommand\ticklist{0,30,...,330}`.
- `xticklabels={}`: Turns off all ticklabels showing the degrees, as these are added manually later.
- `y tick label style={left}`: By default the "y"-ticklabels are placed above the horizontal line. Due to the rotation they are place by the vertical line, and `above` doesn't work very well there. Therefor I place them `left` instead.
- `tick style={draw=none}`: The tickmarks were pointing in very wrong directions, so I turn them off completely.

#### Adding the xticklabels

You could add a series of nodes of the form `\node [anchor={atan2(cos(30),sin(30))+180}] at (axis cs:30,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) {30};` inside the `polaraxis` environment, replacing all the occurrences of `30` with other angles. That is rather inconvenient, and using a loop as described in section 8.1 of the `pgfplots` manual didn't work in a `polaraxis`. Instead I use a workaround, as follows.

1. Add `\usetikzlibrary{through}`.
2. Inside the `polaraxis`, add two `coordinates`, one in the center, and one on the outer edge of the axis:

   ```
   \coordinate (top of axis) at (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
   \coordinate (axis center) at (axis cs:0,0);
   ```
3. After `\end{polaraxis}`, add a circular node with

   ```
   \node (axis circle) at (axis center) [circle through={(top of axis)}] {};
   ```

   `circle through` is defined by the `through` library. As the center of the node is in the center of the axis, and it passes through a point on the edge of the axis, the node edge will be placed exactly on the axis edge.
4. Finally the ticklabels are added with

   ```
   \foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using {atan2(cos(\i),sin(\i))}] \i in \ticklist
      \node [anchor={\j+180}] at (axis circle.\j) {\i};
   ```

   `atan2(cos(\i),sin(\i))` transforms from degrees in a "compass like" polar axis, to those in a "normal" polar axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\ticklist{0,30,...,330}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=360,
    width = 0.5\textwidth,
    xticklabel style={font=\large},
    x post scale=-1,rotate=-90,
    xtick=\ticklist,xticklabels={},y tick label style={left},
    tick style={draw=none}
]

\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(45,0.25)};
\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(135,0.5)};
\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(225,0.75)};
\addplot+ [very thick, polar comb] coordinates {(315,1)};

\coordinate (top of axis) at (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\coordinate (axis center) at (axis cs:0,0);
\end{polaraxis}
\node (axis circle) at (axis center) [circle through={(top of axis)}] {};
\foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using {atan2(cos(\i),sin(\i))}] \i in \ticklist
   \node [anchor={\j+180}] at (axis circle.\j) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Wrong labels

The following code seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{polaraxis}[
            xmin=0,xmax=360,
            xtick={0,30,...,330},
            xticklabels={90$^\circ$,60$^\circ$,30$^\circ$,0$^\circ$,330$^\circ$,300$^\circ$,270$^\circ$,240$^\circ$,210$^\circ$,180$^\circ$,150$^\circ$,120$^\circ$},
            width = 0.5\textwidth,
            no markers,
            xticklabel style={font=\large}]
            \addplot+ [polar comb] coordinates {(120,0.5)};
        \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I haven't done much though. The preamble is cleaned up a bit. In the `axis` options the news is that I specified the tick locations explicitly (`xtick={0,30,...,330}`), and I moved the ticklabel for 120 degrees to the end of the list. There is one caveat though:

- This only works when something is plotted.

If you remove the `\addplot` command from the above code, it no longer works.

[image]

Comment: Nice! That is, I'm impressed that you can offer even an inconvenient solution ;).

Comment: @cfr The new one is a little bit less inconvenient.

Comment: Can't upvote twice. It will only let me down-vote the added convenience and I don't want to do that! Too bad - that is quite ingenious.