# Rotating polar pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I rotated my polar plot by 90 degree. To make sure, the y-Line stays at the 90 degree position I used

```
xmin=90,
xmax=450,
```

but now I need my xtick labels back from 0 to 330.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}         
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        y dir=reverse, 
        rotate=90,  
        xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90}, 
        xtick={0,30,...,330},
        xmin=90,
        xmax=450,
        ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,20) (90,30) (180,50) (270, 40)} --cycle;
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about applying the `rotate=90` to `\addplot` instead?  Thus does `\addplot [rotate=90]` do what you want?

Comment: That will only rotate my addplot, not the coordination system.

Comment: What about using a `\rotatebox` around the tikzpicture and leave the plot as-is?